# Registering models to admin app

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

The Django admin application can use your models to automatically build a site area that you can use to create, view, update, and delete records. This can save you a lot of time during development, making it very easy to test your models and get a feel for whether you have the right data. The admin application can also be useful for managing data in production, depending on the type of website.

All you must do to add your models to the admin application is to register them, as shown below

[image]

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Post

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Post)
```

---

Question:

In production environment, Is this the recommended/standard approach to create/update/view data for a model using django admin app(`django.contrib.admin`)?

Comment: Recommended by whom? As opposed to what?

Answer (score 1):

Though it really depends on you. But I think you can use it with care.

Instead of **/admin**, you can use **a very complicated key** which is known only to you.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ......

    url(r'^a-very-complicated-key/', admin.site.urls),

    ......

]
```

Comment: Does the production environments mostly follow /admin approach?

Comment: Either they maintain 2 different interfaces, one for backend where they enable admin, and one for clients where admin is disabled.

Comment: On the small scale they enable admin, but use it in a way I have explained earlier. Get a very complicated key by generating  a large number and use it as key. But you remember that key, or else save it somewhere safe. So you exactly need what is url to go into admin area.

Comment: @overexchange I hope it helps.

Comment: Are these the only two ways?

Comment: Yeah these are the 2 ways. If you have enough resources go for first or else   second is the best one.

Comment: @overexchange, Have u tried the solution??  If you think my solution worked for you then you can vote and select my answer. Thanks for cooperation.

Comment: Knowing cimplicated key, by user of a product is not fair

Comment: But that is not supposed to be used by user but only the administrator and that too at low level. At higher level they maintain 2 seperate to handle both.

Comment: Can't the user of a product be a network administrator maintaining my django product, who frequently add records into models? Admin approach is one I know that I tried. My query was to know recommend ed approach, in such user scenario.

Comment: Then I think we don't have another option either maintain 2 different server or you need to remember the key.

Comment: Why two different server? Many enterprise product s are maintained by network administrator, And non admin users

Comment: My point is, just to add records in models, registering app to admin app, looks weird to me. Why do I need to register?

Comment: I don't want to discuss further here. I just told you the ways. By the way thanks for all these discussions.